# Awesome wm visual anomaly

Tags: awesome-wm

I have Awesome window manager running on a Manjaro-running desktop with nvidia GeForce GTX 750 card using non-free nvidia drivers.

The machine gives off a visual anomaly when scrolling through text, both in a tiled window, or full screen. The anomalies also show up playing video. The anomaly is a horizontal band of "ripples" that appears in the middle of the screen. As I write this post, the ripple does **not** happen when I scroll in the "body" text edit window of the Stackoverflow page, but does appear and distort text in that text edit field when I scroll a comparable amount using the slider on the right edge of the browser window, scrolling the whole page, not just the post text. I do not remember seeing such an anomaly when running Linux Mint with the cinnamon desktop environment, but it did happen when I added Awesome wm to that Mint install. I run two monitors and the effect happens on both. Note that this anomaly does not happen on another Awesome-running machine I have, so it's not inherent to the window manager.

Comment: Could this be screen tearing? Google image search for "tearing in text" has some results (although I am not sure they really show tearing...).

Comment: Random idea would also be to try running awesome with the `--no-argb` command line argument. That gets rid of transparency support and works around some X11 video driver bugs. (No, I do not know how you can specify command line arguments for your WM in Manjaro, sorry.)

Comment: @UliSchlachter it is not screen tearing, not so extreme as that. I am thinking it is more likely an x11 issue than an Awesome wm issue per se. It may simply manifest under the community Awesome ISO of Manjaro because that one is less "automatic" in configuration. Danke